# I can log in successfully through Keycloak on a site I am running, but I cannot log out and an error occurs. How do I resolve this?

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak

First, to explain the situation, there are a total of three sites in operation, which I will specify as services.
Currently, when Keycloak SSO is connected, there are service1, service2, and service3.
You log in from service1, and then service2 and 3 automatically log in in that order.
Here, if I log out from service1, it works fine, but the following error occurs in service2 and 3.

```
2023-10-17 13:45:13.149 DEBUG 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /user/logout
2023-10-17 13:45:13.152  WARN 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.k.c.u.DelegatingSerializationFilter    : Could not set ObjectFilter: null
2023-10-17 13:45:13.152  WARN 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.k.c.u.DelegatingSerializationFilter    : Could not set ObjectFilter: null
2023-10-17 13:45:13.152 DEBUG 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=KeycloakAuthenticationToken [Principal=05d8e6be-cfdd-4593-b053-7d6f54d2ebb3, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@37774961, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_DEFAULT-ROLES-SSO-GROUP1, ROLE_UMA_AUTHORIZATION, ROLE_USER, ROLE_OFFLINE_ACCESS]]]
2023-10-17 13:45:13.152 DEBUG 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=KeycloakAuthenticationToken [Principal=05d8e6be-cfdd-4593-b053-7d6f54d2ebb3, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@37774961, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_DEFAULT-ROLES-SSO-GROUP1, ROLE_UMA_AUTHORIZATION, ROLE_USER, ROLE_OFFLINE_ACCESS]]]
2023-10-17 13:45:13.152 DEBUG 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Logging out [KeycloakAuthenticationToken [Principal=05d8e6be-cfdd-4593-b053-7d6f54d2ebb3, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@37774961, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_DEFAULT-ROLES-SSO-GROUP1, ROLE_UMA_AUTHORIZATION, ROLE_USER, ROLE_OFFLINE_ACCESS]]]
2023-10-17 13:45:13.154  WARN 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.k.c.u.DelegatingSerializationFilter    : Could not set ObjectFilter: null
2023-10-17 13:45:13.155  WARN 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.k.c.u.DelegatingSerializationFilter    : Could not set ObjectFilter: null
2023-10-17 13:45:13.159  WARN 10428 --- [nerContainer-28] o.k.c.u.DelegatingSerializationFilter    : Could not set ObjectFilter: null
2023-10-17 13:45:13.159  WARN 10428 --- [nerContainer-28] o.k.c.u.DelegatingSerializationFilter    : Could not set ObjectFilter: null
2023-10-17 13:45:13.165 ERROR 10428 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.k.a.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext : failed to invoke remote logout

org.keycloak.adapters.ServerRequest$HttpFailure: null
    at org.keycloak.adapters.ServerRequest.error(ServerRequest.java:287) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-22.0.1.jar:22.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.ServerRequest.invokeLogout(ServerRequest.java:85) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-22.0.1.jar:22.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext.logout(RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext.java:84) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-22.0.1.jar:22.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakLogoutHandler.handleSingleSignOut(KeycloakLogoutHandler.java:78) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-22.0.1.jar:22.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakLogoutHandler.logout(KeycloakLogoutHandler.java:70) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-22.0.1.jar:22.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.CompositeLogoutHandler.logout(CompositeLogoutHandler.java:54) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:99) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:96) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-22.0.1.jar:22.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142) ~[spring-session-core-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-22.0.1.jar:22.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-22.0.1.jar:22.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.79.jar:9.0.79]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

When I debug the log above and look more closely, I see that the invokeLogout method is executed in ServerRequest.class, but a 400 error code appears there. However, when I compared the data when logging out was successful and when it was not, there was no difference, so I cannot think of a solution.

The specification is that keycloak version 22.0.1, redis, and postgresql are installed with Docker, and the security code is written with java and SpringBoot version 2.7.15.

We will also share the source code.

```
[pom.xml]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>security</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <keycloak-adapter.version>22.0.1</keycloak-adapter.version>
        <springdoc.version>1.6.6</springdoc.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak-adapter.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
          <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
[application.properties]
keycloak.realm=realm
keycloak.resource=client
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8999
keycloak.credentials.secret=XxIavd2UUMQPRaQnI9oUHfv01Fk9pBCe
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8999/realms/realm
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8999/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs

keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=false
security.config.use-keycloak=false
keycloak.ssl-required=none
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-stacktrace=always

spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

```
[Controller.java]
@GetMapping("/user/logout")
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){
          new KeycloakLogoutHandler(restTemplate).logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect:/user/main";
       }
```

```
[KeycloakLogoutHandler.java]
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken;
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

@Configuration
public class KeycloakLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KeycloakLogoutHandler.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public KeycloakLogoutHandler(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
      Authentication auth) {
        if (auth == null) {
            logger.warn("Cannot log out without authentication");
            return;
          }
          else if (!KeycloakAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(auth.getClass())) {
              logger.warn("Cannot log out a non-Keycloak authentication: {}", auth);
            return;
          }
        logoutFromKeycloak((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) auth);

        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        
    }

    private void logoutFromKeycloak(KeycloakAuthenticationToken token) {
        KeycloakPrincipal user = (KeycloakPrincipal) token.getPrincipal();
        AccessToken accessToken = token.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
        
        String endSessionEndpoint = accessToken.getIssuer() + "/protocol/openid-connect/logout";
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
          .fromUriString(endSessionEndpoint)
        .queryParam("id_token_hint", user.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdTokenString());

        ResponseEntity<String> logoutResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(
        builder.toUriString(), String.class);
        if (logoutResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            logger.info("Successfulley logged out from Keycloak");
            System.out.println("Successfulley logged out from Keycloak");
        } else {
            logger.error("Could not propagate logout to Keycloak");
            System.out.println("Could not propagate logout to Keycloak");
        }
    }

}
```

```
[SecurityConfig.java]
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@KeycloakConfiguration //1
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "security.config.use-keycloak", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = false)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { //2

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
    
    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;  
    
    SecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {   
        this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler; 
    }   
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { //3
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/user").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/user/userAndAdmin").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/scss/**", "/vendor/**", "/webfonts/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/user/main");
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { //4
        auth.authenticationProvider(getKeycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    private KeycloakAuthenticationProvider getKeycloakAuthenticationProvider() { //5
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        var mapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        mapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
        authenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(mapper);

        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() { //6
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }
    
    @Bean
    protected SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

I wondered if it was because the ID Token value had changed, so I compared the Token value on each service site, and the data was the same, and I saw Logged out in the log, but I don't know why Keycloak didn't log out properly.

Comment: You know that Keycloak adapters for Spring where deprecated almost 2 years ago and that active maintenance had stopped even before that, right?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).